# Java: is 'Three Stooges' example really immutable?

Tags: java, immutability

In `Java Concurrency In Practice`, the following example is given to illustrate how to create an immutable class:

http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/listings/ThreeStooges.java

This class has: `private final Set<String> stooges = new HashSet<String>();` which is initialized in its Constructor:

```
public ThreeStooges() {
    stooges.add("Moe");
    stooges.add("Larry");
    stooges.add("Curly");
}
```

and has a method

```
public boolean isStooge(String name) {
    return stooges.contains(name);
}
```

to see if a name is one of the three stooges.

But when I do this: `ThreeStooges ts = new ThreeStooges()`, is it guaranteed that the object will be properly constructed (i.e. the state of `stooges` correctly initialized) before its reference is set into `ts`?

In other words, if I publish this object, is it possible that some thread will see it as incorrectly initialized (i.e. it will see `stooges` as empty when accessed through `isStooge()`)?

My understanding is that an immutable object will be properly constructed and correctly visible when it's published - (because it uses final instance variables). Is my understanding correct? If yes, is this class still immutable?

EDIT: it seems from the comments I saw that it's difficult to believe an object can be seen by other threads before its Constructor completes. Here's a link on that: http://jeremymanson.blogspot.in/2008/05/double-checked-locking.html

Comment: You're asking if the object is created and initialized before `ts` points at it? As if the reference would be set and then some magic would *continue* object initialization?

Comment: @Dave Newton yes. That's why e.g. we need to use 'volatile' instance in double checked locking for Singleton.

Comment: I don't understand; you're suggesting an object's ctor won't be finished yet, but the object is returned?

Comment: @Dave Newton yes. http://jeremymanson.blogspot.in/2008/05/double-checked-locking.html

Comment: That is addressing something rather different.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A whole heap of wrong answers here :(

The initialization safety guarantees for final fields in the Java Memory Model are surprisingly strong.  Not only do they guarantee that writes to final fields in the constructor are visible to any thread which obtains a shared reference to the object (even if that reference is obtained via a data race), but they guarantee that any writes in the constructor *through* that reference are visible to reads through that reference.  The only caveat is that the reference to the object under construction not escape during construction.  Of course, if the class were to mutate the object after construction, or offer a way for clients to get at the object reference to the HashSet, all bets are off.

The purpose of this guarantee is to prevent the need for tricky reasoning about the state of immutable (in this case, effectively immutable) objects.  IF the field is final AND there are no writes to the referred-to- object's state other than those in the constructor, you're done.

If this makes your head hurt, don't worry.  If you (a) make the reference field private and final and (b) do not modify the state of the referred-to object outside the constructor and (c) do not provide any access that would let a client do the same (e.g., no mutative methods, no getter that exposes the field, etc), you're done.

Comment: Are you 'the Brian Goetz'? I keep re-reading your excellent book, and your articles on IBM site. Am a big fan! An honor to interact with you!

Comment: it's probably more accurate to say "any write before constructor exit is visible to any read (of the same variable), if the read is through a final field"

Answer (score 2):

I can't see any possible case when a thread would access the object before it is entirely initialized. You can see the constructor as a normal function that returns a completely new reference. Because the reference is new, I don't think any other thread (other than the creating thread) is accessing it before initialization.

Comment: E.g. say there's a list shared by multiple threads, and one thread publishes an instance of this class through adding it to the list. Will other threads see it as incorrectly published?

Comment: Never. Before the adding thread can publish the object, it must have its reference. The reference is returned by the constructor after the object is being initialized.

Comment: In other words, no one can interact with the object if it hasn't a reference to it. Before the thread adds an object to the list, it must have it's reference. The first reference is obtained after the initialization by the thread that creates it. So you shouldn;t worry.

Comment: Well, I can do this: list.add(new ThreeStooges());

Answer (score 1):

This class is immutable because you don't expose any functions that can change the `stooges` set.

Because `stooges` is final, it is guaranteed to be completely initialized after construction. In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6599751/314784) the following rule is quoted and explained:

> A thread that can only see a reference to an object after that object
>   has been completely initialized is guaranteed to see the correctly
>   initialized values for that object's final fields.

Since the entries are added *during* the construction and no elements are added later, all threads should be able to have a correct view of the `stooges` set.

Comment: I have elaborated on this a bit. Does this help?

Comment: Well, 'stooges' will be seen by threads to point to a Set because that's what happens when it's *created*. But the constructor can run some other time, so a thread may be able to see an empty set. May be the link I added in the question would help clarify my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
private final Set<String> stooges = new HashSet<String>();

public ThreeStooges() {
    stooges.add("Moe");
    stooges.add("Larry");
    stooges.add("Curly");
}
```

This code is immutable because the set `stooges` is declared `final`. However, here only the class is immutable but not the set as the elements can be added anytime by the same class. Here the set can only be constructed once and you cannot change the `references`

In the case of visibility, they are not visible since the set is `private`. If you make it `public`, they are seen only after construction since the object has to be constructed before monitored.

Comment: Ok, but my question is about visibility guarantee of an immutable class.